# Phase Unwrapping Issue of IQ data sample in Radar Signal Processing

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, phase, radar, complex

I am doing radar sensor signal processing.
The radar sensor gives iq data corresponding to the range (sweeps).
I want to detect micro motion so that phase analysis is used.

Sweep is the distance measurement range. One sweep consists of 259 data points (L = 259).

Each sweep is noise-reducing lowpass filtered using

```
 y(s) = alpha_iq * y(s-1) + (1 - alpha_iq)* x(s)
```

**alpha_iq** is the smoothing factor (**alpha_iq** = 0.535261).
**y(s)** is the output sweep and **x(s)** is the input sweep (output data sample/signal from Radar Sensor).

To extract the phase, unwrapping of the phase of the IQ samples

[image]

**θ[s]** is the unwrapped phase of a sweep. **αθ** = 0.995012, is a high pass filter to remove any build up of phase over time, **L** is the number of fast time samples, **s** is sweep index, **d** is range index, **∠** is the phase of complex number, and  y∗D is the complex conjugate of yD. yD(s,d) is the low pass filtered sweep.

The problem I am facing is that, for detecting a *moving object, static object, and non-moving object*
this unwrapping of phase is used. But I cannot find  difference in the unwrapped phase of these 3 objects.
For non-moving objects it shows phase change. How can we separate the unwrapped phase of these 3 objects?
I am attaching the plot of 100 phase array of these 3 cases

Static object:

[image: Static ObjectUnwrappedPhase]

Human chest movement:

[image: Human Chestmovement UnwrappedPhase]

Non-moving object:

[image: NonMovingObject Unwrapped Phase]

Anyone please help me to solve this issue or give me another solution to extract the phase so that we can differentiate these 3 cases.

Comment: Sorry, your phase calculation is very confusing. Can you provide this as actual math formulas instead of code snippets. Why do you have to take the mean of what looks like a single sample? Is your variable $s$ time of frequency ?

Comment: I have added the original equation.